# How to ask User in flutter (web, ios, android) for cookie management to be GDPR compliant when you use Firebase configuration?

Tags: flutter, firebase, analytics, firebase-analytics, gdprconsentform

In my Flutter app, I am using Firebase and Analytics in its configuration.
To be GDPR compliant, I have to ask the user if he accepts that I use Analytics.
What is the best way to do it in a Flutter project for web, ios and android?

Firebase is configured in my main.dart :

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      // Initialize FlutterFire
      future: kIsWeb
          ? Firebase.initializeApp(
              options: const FirebaseOptions(
                  apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxx",
                  authDomain: "xxxxxxxxx",
                  databaseURL: "xxxxxxx",
                  projectId: "xxxxxxxxx",
                  storageBucket: "xxxxxxxxx",
                  messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxx",
                  appId: "xxxxxxxxxxx",
                  measurementId: "G-xxxxxxxx"),
            )
          : Firebase.initializeApp(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        // Check for errors
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return const Text("Sorry, closed today for maintenance", textDirection: TextDirection.ltr);
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          return FutureBuilder(
            future: FirebaseAppCheck.instance.activate(
              webRecaptchaSiteKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
              androidProvider: AndroidProvider.playIntegrity,
            ),
            builder: (context, snapshot1) {
              return StreamProvider<TotoUser>.value(
                initialData: null,
                value: AuthService().userStream,
                child: Home(),
              );
            },
          );
          
        }

        return Loading();
      },
    );

  }
}
```

And in the index.html :

```
<script type="module">

import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.1/firebase-app.js";
import { getAnalytics } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.1/firebase-analytics.js";

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "xxxxxx",
  authDomain: "xxxxxx",
  databaseURL: "xxxxxxx",
  projectId: "xxxxxxx",
  storageBucket: "xxxxxxx",
  messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxx",
  appId: "xxxxxxx",
  measurementId: "G-xxxxxxxx"
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
      
  </script>
```

Should I put a dialog before initialize the app and waiting the user answer?
How do you manage the Firebase configuration with Analytics in Flutter and the GDPR compliance?

Thank you so much for your help and advice!